# Mongoose: find() ignore duplicate values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a "chat" mongoose `Schema` which has the following properties:

```js
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    recipient: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    sender: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
    },
    ...
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

Generally, I want to fetch the last message of each coversation that a user has. Meaning that I need to provide a user id (that can be either stored in the `sender` or `recipient` field) and get back the last message (indicated by `createdAt`) the user had with each of the other users.

**Example:**
Let's say I have the following `document`s:

```js
[
  {
    recipient: "One",
    sender: "Two",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z"),

  },
  {
    recipient: "One",
    sender: "Three",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    recipient: "Two",
    sender: "One",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-16T12:05:10Z")
  }
]
```

Instering "One" as input - the desired result from `Model.find(...)` is:

```js
[
  {
    recipient: "One",
    sender: "Three",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    recipient: "Two",
    sender: "One",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-16T12:05:10Z")
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get distinct records values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example data:

```
[
  {
    recipient: "One",
    sender: "Two",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z"),
    content: "Hi Mr. One! - Two"
  },
  {
    recipient: "One",
    sender: "Three",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-15T08:00:00Z"),
    content: "Hello One! - Three"
  },
  {
    recipient: "Two",
    sender: "One",
    createdAt: ISODate("2014-02-16T12:05:10Z"),
    content: "Whats up, Two? - One"
  }
]
```

Have a look at the following aggregation: https://mongoplayground.net/p/DTSDWX3aLWe

It...

- Uses **$match** to filter all messages by recipient or sender. Returns the ones matching the current user (`One`)
- Adds a `conversationWith` field using **$addFields** that contains the `recipient` if it is a message **to user One** or the `sender` if it is a message **sent by user One**
- Sorts the messages by date using **$sort**
- Groups all the messages using **$group** by the new `conversationWith` field and returns the most recent message as `firstMessage`

The full aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            {
              recipient: "One"
            },
            {
              sender: "One"
            }
          ],

        },

      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      conversationWith: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$sender",
              "One"
            ]
          },
          then: "$recipient",
          else: "$sender"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$conversationWith",
      firstMessage: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Using mongoplayground you can remove the aggregation steps one-by-one to see what each step does.

Try:

- Only the **$match** step
- **$match** + **$addFields**
- **$match** + **$addFields** + **$sort**
- [..]

for best understanding.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by aggregation as shown in below query

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/wEi4Y6IZJ2v

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      recipient: 1,
      createdAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$recipient",
      createdAt: {
        $last: "$createdAt"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      recipient: "$_id",
      createdAt: "$createdAt"
    }
  }
])
```

If you have two fields to match, then you  can use below query

Working Example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rk5MxuphLOT

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          sender: "One"
        },
        {
          recipient: "One"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      other: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$recipient",
              "One"
            ]
          },
          then: "$sender",
          else: "$recipient"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$other",
      createdAt: {
        $last: "$createdAt"
      },
      recipient: {
        $last: "$recipient"
      },
      sender: {
        $last: "$sender"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      recipient: "$recipient",
      sender: "$sender",
      createdAt: "$createdAt"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/E0G67cotQvL

Thank you. What if I want the same, but for two fields - I mean I want to search for a specific user and fetch the documents in which the user exists in the `sender` or `recipient` - but after find them, take only those of the "last".
For being more clear - I have a collection of messages between people (private chat) - I want to fetch the last user's message on each conversation he had (whether he is the sender or the recipient)

Comment: @RonRofe Updated answer added a new example for the use case mentioned in the comment

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rely on mongodb to filter out duplicates, its better to never even allow to have duplicates by creating a [unique index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/).

since it seems your recipients are nested in a parent scheme, I would do the filtering of the duplicates in nodejs since its hard to untangle this in a mongodb query.
If you need to use mongodb, use the [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) function or the [aggregate pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and be inspired by [this article](https://www.compose.com/articles/finding-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb/)

Comment: So your suggestion is to fetch all of the `document`s and make this filtering with js?